# How do you enable the logging of all queries to postgreSQL AWS RDS instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to monitor all queries to my postgresql instance. Following [these steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html), I created a custom db parameter group, set `log_statement` to `all` and `log_min_duration_statement` to `1`, applied the parameter group to my instance, and rebooted it. Then I fired a `POST` request to the instance but a record of query wasn't to be found in the `Recent Events & Logs` tab of my instance. Doing a `SELECT * FROM table` query in `psql` however shows that the resource was created and the post request worked. What am I missing in order to see the logs?

Answer (score 5):

Setting `log_min_duration_statement` to `1` tells Postgres to only log queries that take longer than 1 ms. If you set it to `0` instead, all queries will be logged (the default, no logging, is `-1`).

Comment: `-1` disables logging. `0` logs all statements: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-MIN-DURATION-STATEMENT

Comment: @AdamFlanagan Thanks. Updated my answer with that info.

Comment: how long does it take for the new parameter settings to take effect? and suppose i change the above value (which is of type `dynamic`).. changing it instantly modifies the db.. once the modification is done.. does that mean the new parameter should take effect immediately? it's not in my case

Comment: Setting it to -1 doesn't disable logging. As per the documentation it "Causes the duration of each completed statement to be logged if the statement ran for at least the specified amount of time."

Answer (score 4):

You followed the right [steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_LogAccess.Concepts.PostgreSQL.html), all that is left is to make sure the parameter group is properly applied to your Postgres instance. Look at the Parameter Group in the Configuration Details tab of your instance, and make sure they have the right group name followed by "in-sync".
A reboot is usually required when changing parameter groups on an instance, this may be what is (was?) missing in your case.

Comment: I have proper parameter followed by in-sync. But still log_destination is disabled for postgresql.